# Play with Play cookie session

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4, cookie-session

When I set a value to session (cookie session), I can see that value from the client like below

[image: firefox request cookies]

However, when I try to get the cookie with javascript `document.cookie`, this is all I get

[image]

How can I get the *PLAY_SESSION* cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the session cookie in the JavaScript of your browser. [For security reasons](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) it's set to http-only.

If you just want to persist some small data between requests you can set your own cookie in the response of an action. Just set the http-only flag to false:

```
response().setCookie(
    "theme",        // name
    "blue",         // value
    3600,           // maximum age
    "/some/path",   // path
    ".example.com", // domain
    false,          // secure
    false           // http only
);
```

With the http-only flag set to false you can access your cookie from your JavaScript within the browser.

Comment: If I cannot get the session cookie, then how can Firefox display the data?

Comment: Firefox can, it's the browser - I know it's unfair :( .

Comment: LOL :))). My goal is not to read or modify the cookie, but to better understand the security level this mechanism can offer.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer at first as I did not know what httponly flag is. Perhaps you can adapt your answer to explain that better.

Comment: Tried as best as I can.